# Auth0: The customize lock screen kept popping up (AngularJs)

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock

I downloaded the auth0 quick-start project, AngularJs SPA, to start my application from https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs-samples/tree/master/01-Login. It works fine without any issue.

However, when I follow the instruction from https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v11/ui-customization to customize my lock UI, the first time the lock UI appears, but afterward, the lock dialog kept appearing. Below is my code snipped:

```
function run(authService) {
    // Handle the authentication
      // result in the hash
      debugger;
      // Initializing our Auth0Lock
      var options = {
          theme: {
              logo: 'assets/images/cat.png',
              primaryColor: "#0077be"
          },
          languageDictionary: {
              title: "Log in"
          },
          auth: {
              redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:23321/#/callback'
          }
      }
      var lock = new Auth0Lock(AUTH0_CLIENT_ID, AUTH0_DOMAIN, options);
      lock.show();

     // original code from quickstart
      authService.handleAuthentication();
  }
```

I tried to place the options in the login function in authService.js, but it still not working. I tried to comments out the lock.show(), then the standard lock UI appears instead.   Could anyone here please help?  Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Sample](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-angularjs-samples/tree/master/01-Login) uses Hosted login pages by default. To change the Lock UI in hosted pages, you need to apply the UI configurations in your [hosted pages](https://manage.auth0.com/#/login_page) instead rather than in the Application code.

If you are using Lock in embedded mode, i.e there is no redirect to Auth0 [Authorization](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#social) endpoint `/authorize`, you would then need to modify the Lock configuration from within the Application itself.